# Stateless session inside @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, stateless-session

I'm currently having problem with executing transaction inside stateless session.

On a service layer i have defined transaction using `@Transactional` annotation (which is required because the methods needs to be in one transaction).
Inside the method I create new entity `Car`. 
However I also have to create in underlaying methods custom transtaction inside stateless session (its done for performance) like this

```
StatelessSession session = getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction()

// create and setup CarRequirements entity

transaction.commit;
```

Problem is that the entity `CarRequirements` has foreign key to entity `Car`. Therefore when i try to commit the underlaying transaction an exception occurs because obviously the `Car` entity is not yet commited to database.

Is there a way to postpone the commit of underlaying transaction or force commit of the `Car` entity?

Comment: How these entities are mapped ?

Comment: @davidxxx the CarRequirement has foreign key that references primary key of Car

Answer (score 2):

either you define a relationship between CarRequirements and Car (cascade)
or you have to save a Car firstly then save CareRequirements

Comment: Cascading is not a option for me because these entities already have relationship (CarRequirement has foreign key that references primary key of Car)..
As for the other suggestion, I am saving the Car first but because it is inside transactional annotation it is commited later than CarRequirement which is commited inside stateless session.

For now I solved it by splitting the method into two. One that is marked by transactional annotation and creates and commits the Car and one that in stateless session creates CarRequirements entity. It works this way but I dont like having it separated.